# How to unify records in one line - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, pivot

I have a `teacher` table and I also have a `phone` table where the link is through the person's ID. When I look up the phone numbers of each professor, it appears like this:

```
(SELECT
       T.ID_TEACHER,
       P.PHONE,
       P.NUMBER 
FROM TEACHER T LEFT JOIN PHONES P 
ON P.IDPERSON = T.ID_TEACHER)
```

| ID_TEACHER | PHONE | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xxxxxxx |
| 1 | 2 | xxxxxxxx |
| 1 | 3 | xxxxxxx |
| 2 | 1 | xxxxxxx |

However, I would like it to be shown like this:

| ID_TEACHER | PHONE | NUMBER | PHONE | NUMBER | PHONE | NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xxxxx | 2 | xxxxx | 3 | xxxxx |
| 2 | 1 | xxxxxxxxx |  |  |  |  |

How do I do? I'm using MYSQL. I didn't find a solution.

Comment: You can search for "PIVOT"

Comment: Sadly MySQL doesn't have pivot, so you'll need to utilize some trick, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional aggregation:

Try the below:

```
   SELECT
    T.ID_TEACHER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 1 THEN P.PHONE ELSE NULL END) AS PHONE1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 1 THEN P.NUMBER ELSE NULL END) AS NUMBER1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 2 THEN P.PHONE ELSE NULL END) AS PHONE2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 2 THEN P.NUMBER ELSE NULL END) AS NUMBER2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 3 THEN P.PHONE ELSE NULL END) AS PHONE3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN P.PHONE = 3 THEN P.NUMBER ELSE NULL END) AS NUMBER3
FROM TEACHER T
LEFT JOIN PHONES P ON P.IDPERSON = T.ID_TEACHER
GROUP BY T.ID_TEACHER
```

Comment: You've used `P.NUMBER` as the output for every `PHONE{n}` column instead of `P.PHONE`.